# SignalR - Individual variables

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am using **SignalR** to setup a connection between my client and my server. I would like to store some user data on init. When the user calls a method I want access to these variables to do some calculations and send a response back to the client.

I can not use static variables because I want these variables to be individual for each client. Saving these variables in one global dictionary seems not performant for a lot of users. Saving the data in a database is not an option because the client will call a method approximately every 15-30 seconds and this for a few minutes and then the hub can be disposed.

What I am trying to archieve is one hub instance per client. One open connection with the server, 1-on-1. Is this possible with SignalR and how or do I have to look for another library?

Thanks a lot,

Have a great day!

Comment: I think you have this wrong. One hub per caller would be less efficient. Use the single dictionary approach (I might not fo it as a static dictionary personally, but you're along the right track).

Comment: This dictionary has to be static right... or else the next time the user calls a hub method the data will be lost?

Comment: Yes, if you use a non static member then it will not work. All I was saying is that if you don't like static variables (disclaimer: I don't) then you could declare a single dictionary and feed it through the hub constructor (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by trying to get a hub instance per client connection is pretty hard since **hubs are designed to be just the opposite** (a way to talk to some or all clients connected)

you are probably looking for the [Persistent Connection API](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/PersistentConnection)

PS: I don't really see why you rule out a db so quickly since you could always use an in memory cache like [redis](https://redis.io/).